# Making ndarrays callable

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose I have a set of orthonormal basis functions, represented as Python callables

```
class Basis(object):

    def __init__(self,i,j):
        self.i=i
        self.j=j

    def __call__(self,x,y):
        return f(self.i,self.j,x,y)
```

I'd like to store these in a numpy.array, such that `basis_functions[i,j]=Basis(i,j)`

I'd also like the array to be callable, so that `basis_functions(x,y)` returns an array containing `basis_functions[i,j](x,y)` for all `i,j` in range.

I've had a look at the documentation on subclassing ndarray, but haven't found it particularly helpful. Can anybody give me any pointers as to where to start?

ADDENDUM

I was hoping to use it something like this

```
class SytheticFunction(object):
    basis=callable_array([[Basis(i,j) for j in xrange(COLUMNS)]
                          for i in xrange(ROWS)])

    def __init__(self,weights):
        self.weights=weights

    def __call__(self,x,y):
        return (self.weights*SyntheticFunction.basis(x,y)).sum()
```

Comment: yes, you should start by stopping to try and shoehorn numpy into an OOP way of thinking ;). I have the impression there is a perfectly elegant single line of numpy that will do exactly what you want it to.

Comment: That comment is not helpful.

Comment: Its not very actionable advice, for sure, but it is the most helpful comment you are going to get. To make my advice a little more actionable; why don't you describe the actual problem you are trying to solve, so we can take a step back and try and find the best solution?

Comment: I'm trying to create procedurally generated maps. For this, I want to create a callable that generates elevation for a given longitude and latitude as a weighted sum of real spherical harmonics. The naive way to do this would be by summing over nested for loops, but I feel there ought to be a better way.

Comment: Indeed there is a better way than summing over nested loops! Your description is a bit too general for a very specific solution, but I would start with reading up on the topics of vectorization and broadcasting in numpy generally.